# How to use Views/Contextual Filters with a referenced entity

Tags: views

So, I have a site with two content types:

- Sermon Series
- Sermon

The sermon content type has an entity reference field selecting a sermon series that it relates to.

On the page for a sermon series, I am attaching a view to list all the sermons that have the "Sermon Series" field set to that particular series.

Ideally, I'd like to only create one view that will work for every sermon/sermon series.

I know that I need to use contextual filters to do this, but I'm having an exceptionally difficult time wrapping my mind around what settings I need to use, and spending several hours trying stuff out has been to no avail.

Could someone please explain the process to me?

For bonus points- I'd also like to use a view on the sermon page to display an image from the referenced sermon series. I am also not exactly sure how to set this up.

To help clarify, here's the workflow that I want to end up with:

1. User creates a new "Sermon Series" with a title and an image.
2. User creates a new "Sermon", and they can select which "Sermon Series" it belongs to.
3. The new sermon shows up in a list on the corresponding "Sermon Series" page.
4. The image related to the "Sermon Series" shows up on the "Sermon" page.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use module [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](http://drupal.org/project/eva) it provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are all examples of entity content.

There is a [screencast](http://vimeo.com/31781424) on how to use that module

hope that helps for you...